# Bitmap в byte, byte в string, string в byte и byte в Bitmap. Вообщем сохранение изображения

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, byte

Делаю сохранение изображения в xml файл, Для этого я изначально Bitmap превращаю в byte array

```
Bitmap bitmapSave = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uriSave);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmapSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] b = stream.toByteArray();
```

Дальше я этот массив загоняю в строчку и получаю такое значение: `[B@59710c4`

```
`org.w3c.dom.Element photo = doc.createElement("photo");
 photo.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(b.toString()));
 photosElement.appendChild(photo);
 stream.close();
```

Дальше я сохраняю этот xml файл в папку итд..

А теперь загрузка:
Получаю значение которое получил из byte array, получаю все как надо `[B@59710c4`

```
String strLoad = elementsLoad.get(i).text();
```

Дальше я получаю в массив из строки byte's

```
byte[] imgBytes = strLoad.getBytes();
```

Вот казалось бы и все, но проблема в том что массив по сравнению с изначальным получается очень маленьким, и когда я получаю Bitmap и присваиваю его ImageView, то ImageView становиться белым. Т.е присваивается белая картинка.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytes, 100, imgBytes.length);
```

Comment: [Вот это](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684665/java-byte-array-to-string-to-byte-array) не о том что вас интересует?..

Comment: И ещё [вот этот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466870/java-convert-string-bytes-to-readable-string?lq=1) момент, про значение `[B@59710c4`. Вообще, я бы рекомендовал в xml сохранять закодированный base64 массив байт, если уж очень надо. А в идеале - вообще не хранить бинарные данные в текстовом формате.

Answer (score 4):

В общем, если взять выжимку из моих комментариев, то ответ получается такой:

1. `photo.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(b.toString()));`
   `b.toString();` не преобразует массив байтов в строку, а преобразует в строку **объект** массив байтов. Т.е. значение `[B@59710c4`, которое Вы получили, означает: "массив байтов по адресу 0x59710c4", сохранять которое в файл, как Вы сами понимаете, бессмысленно.
2. Чтобы сохранить в файл Ваш массив надо использовать `Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP)`.
3. Соответственно, при загрузке используйте `byte[] imgBytes = Base64.decode(strLoad, Base64.NO_WRAP);`

P.S: [Base64](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html)